# How does S Pen (Samsung) show cursor on screen?

Tags: samsung, android-sdk, s-pen

I would like to know how does samsung android os show the pen cursor when I took the pen out and point over screen without touching the screen? It is a miracle for me. I cannot find any sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Break it down-How does the S pen work?](http://www.androidauthority.com/break-it-down-how-does-the-s-pen-work-154435/) offers a nice explanation along with a link to video too

- S pen pulls power from the device wirelessly
- > Electromagnetic field that provides power to the pen can also be used to calculate its position relative to the screen. This, along with information from the S Pen button and the nib on the end are what is used to determine what the user it doing with the S Pen.
- Pressure sensitivity is built in the stylus
- To summarize

  > An electromagnetic field is generated from a circuit behind the screen. The S Pen picks this up and uses it to power itself and figure out its position relative to the screen. It sends this, along with information from the S Pen button and the nib at the end, back to the Note.

Edit: Video in linked post makes it clear ascend easy to understand